# Using managed C++ assembly in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dll, managed-c++

I am building an MVC ASP.NET application where I now need to reference and use a managed C++ assembly. Specifically it is about Kakadu, a JPEG 2000 codec library.

The managed C++ assembly in turn references two native DLLs. When I try to run the application I get the following error:

`Could not load file or assembly 'kdu_mni.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.`

`kdu_mni.DLL` is the name of the managed C++ assembly, which is located in the bin folder, along with the two other native DLLs it needs. However, it seems that the CLR cannot find those, apparently because the bin folder is not in the executable search path. Placing the two native DLLs for example under `C:\windows` solves the issue, but I am looking for a more elegant solution.

What would be the best way to deploy these dependencies along with the rest files of my application?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but for others hitting the same issue. I had this problem because of a DLL that was used that referenced the 'kdu_mni.DLL'. Even though the functionality we used did not need the 'kdu_mni.DLL'.

Long story short 'kdu_mni.DLL' was compiled for x64(AMD) so IIS refuses to load it. Our solution was simply to ensure it was not deployed in the web site bin directory as IIS tries to load everything in there.

btw copying 'kdu_mni.DLL' and/or its dependencies to C:\Windows did not work.